# Why am I getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named" Error Python Packages

Tags: python, site-packages

I am a beginner, but have some understanding and would appreciate any help.

I have am getting the ModuleNotFoundError for 2 packages; one is my own called `crs_prisma` and the other is the `github` package from `pip install`.

I run `pip install github` and it's successful. I have checked the folder in `appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages` and have confirmed the github package is there, and I am running `v1.2.7`. When I run `pip list` it also comes up `github 1.2.7`

When I run `python --version` I get `Python 3.10.0` as expected. In my script I have tried importing it as both `from github import Github` and `import github` neither of which work and both give me the error:

> from github import Github
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'github'

My other module, a class called `crs_prisma` is also returning the not found error. The structure is

> crs_prisma
>
> --> **init**.py
>
> --> prisma
>
> |----> **init**.py
>
> |----> prisma_class.py
>
> --> script.py

and I am trying to import the methods from that class/package using

```
from crs_prisma.prisma.prisma_class import *
```

Yet again, I receive the `ModuleNotFound` Error.

Note - previously, this was working. The only difference is that I uninstalled and then reinstalled Python as I had a module-caching issue, in which when I run my script, it was somehow running an old version of my class and not reflecting the changes - none of the articles online solved my issue.

Does anyone have any ideas what's going on here?

Yet when I run my script I get

Answer (score 0):

For importing your own package, the `crs_prisma`, you might need to define an environment variable called `PYTHONPATH`, and add the path to where this file is located.

For the package `github`, it seems that the `import github` statement is correct, I would recommend to reinstall it, i.e. `pip uninstall github`, then, perhaps try `python -m pip install github`, this ensures there isn't any mismatch between python and pip.